# I can't select faces with left mouse button

Tags: objects

I tried following a tutorial to make something simple and ran in to a problem straight away.

From the default cube: I can select it in Object Mode (object turns orange). I switch to Edit Mode, I can only select a face with right click and not left. When I left click, no list of options appears as I expected there to be.

So I can't move on from there.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have sound enabled in the tutorial? Most if not all of the 3d view menus are usually accessed through keyboard shortcuts. If the tutorial doesn't mention any shortcut it uses it might be meant for more advanced users or be bad quality one.

Comment: The guy on the tutorial just said to switch from object mode to edit mode, click face select, then right click on the face that I'm supposed to delete and click delete. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6X9YjsR5wSA  between 30 and 45 seconds. Is what isn't working for me.

Comment: He says "click (=press) X to delete the face" and the video too shows "X" key icon in bottom left corner.

Comment: Oh.  How silly of me. I didn't hear him say x. I only heard right click > delete. Thanks for pointing that out. :) Much! appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is characteristic to blender. With the left mouse button you change the position for the 3d cursor and with the right mouse button you can select objects.

In edit mode you can use the W shortcut, which give you a list of modelling actions. You can also use the left bar or the options in the menubar below.

[image]
[image]

Take a look at this tutorial about navigating in Blender:
http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/learning-keyboard-mouse-navigation.php